# What is the fastest way to extract all the subpaths from a path using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For a given path, for example - `abc/def/hijkl/mno.txt` how to extract all the paths like below

```
abc
abc/def
abc/def/hijkl
abc/def/hijkl/mno.txt
```

Like an array with actual path and all the sub paths till the root path.

I've tried the getting this with regex but I do not find a way to match every occurrence of `/` from the beginning of the string.

Below is the regex I've tried

```
(.*?)?\/+
```

Is there any way to get this output with regex in javascript

Comment: Regex is not what you need as you cannot match at the same location more than once. Split with `/` and then build the output from the resulting chunks.

Comment: Also if you're working with paths I'm guessing node.js? If so the built-in path module is going to be **extremely** preferable to a hand-rolled regex.

Comment: ...unless they are URL paths @JaredSmith. I've seen more than one attempt at using node's `path` module to manipulate URL paths with predictably tragic results.

Comment: @spender which is also funny because there's a built-in URL module too lol. I will never understand why people (including me, I'm occasionally guilty too) will start coding a hand rolled solution without doing at least 1 google search worth of due diligence to see if there's a built-in solution. Of course if we're talking URLs then OP is covered in the browser too.

Comment: @JaredSmith The [`URL` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) doesn't really have any methods to manipulate paths (unless you consider `new URL('..', base).pathname`, but even there `base` needs to be a full URL not just a path). Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Bergi no and that's a fair point, but my point is more about how people get stuck on the first potential solution that presents itself instead of taking a step back and considering options for even the barest fraction of a second, i.e. the infamous X/Y problem. I find this a *fascinating* (and frequently annoying, all the more so because I occasionally exhibit it) facet of human behavior. This question was "how do I write this regex for something that regex is inappropriate for" not "hey I need to manipulate a path in a URL and the builtin interface seems lacking".

Comment: @JaredSmith Ah, yes. And [when they choose regex, they even get one extra problem](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Regexp for this.

You can just split your string into an array using `split`, then reconstitute slices of that array back into paths using `join`.

```js
const path = "abc/def/hijkl/mno.txt";

const segments = path.split('/');

const paths = segments.map((s, i) => segments.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'))

console.log(paths)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string by `/` and append the array list as you desire:

Example:

```js
const str = `abc/def/hijkl/mno.txt`;

let array = str.split('/');

res=""
len=array.length;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   res+=array[i];
   console.log(res);
   if(i<len-1)
   res+="/";

}
```